# Ubuntu Touch how to detect If the application is closed

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, qml

on ubuntu touch.
I run an application in terminal and close the application in the Application scope.
The application isn't killed. And no event is caught in QQuickView.

How do I detect this close event?

Comment: Today I tried it on the new image. It is killed using SIGTERM in Application scope now. I guess it is fixed now. Now I can just catch signal SIGTERM and do a grace clean up.

Comment: Don't know how to do it in QML though

Comment: Did you test my answer with the new 14.04 image?

Answer (score 0):

The close event in QML seems to be a recent addition (Qt 5.1) so only 14.04 which provides Qt 5.2 will be able to catch such event with this kind of handler:

```
import QtQuick 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.1

Window {
    onClosing: {
        console.log("Bye")
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also use `onVisibleChanged` signal handler.

Sources:

- https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31019
- https://codereview.qt-project.org/#change,55457

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this on Ubuntu touch. There is no Window available. There is no onClosing for MainView. I am not sure whether I have installed the correct package.

Comment: You should test this code on a daily image to ensure that you have Qt5.2. Where did you get your current image?

Comment: phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/tmp$ qmlscene main.qml <br> --desktop_file_hint=/home/phable phable/ phablet/ phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/tmp$ qmlscene main.qml --desktop_file_hint=/home/phablet/.local/share/click/hooks/desktop/com.ubuntu.te‌​rminal_terminal_0.5.53.desktop <br> callbacks 0xb3d925f9 0xb3d925a5 <br>  creating surface at (0, 58) with size (768, 1222) with title 'Window 1'Terminated <br>  phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~/tmp$ cat main.qml <br>  import QtQuick 2.1 <br>  import QtQuick.Window 2.1 <br>  Window { <br>  onClosing: {  <br> console.log("Bye") <br>  } <br>  }

Comment: I have verified that I am using qt 5.2.1. I tried your example.  Run it and close the application in the application scope. I still cannot see the  "Bye" in the output. I think the application is simply get killed.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
MainView {
    id: myApp
    objectName: "myApp"
    Component.onDestruction: {
        console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~ bye!!! ~~~~~~~~~');
    }
```

Best regards!